# Cmake --build error, GPT4ALL , Cannot open include file: 'unistd.h'

Tags: python, large-language-model, gpt4all

I am trying to run gpt4all model on my windows 10, but when i run this command 'cmake --build . --parallel' I got this error

> Cannot open include file: 'unistd.h': No such file or directory [D:\projects\gpt4all\gpt4all-backend\build\llmodel.vcxproj]